# Python WEBDRIVER - I can't select an element from a listbox and submit my answer

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

I would like to select an element from a listbox and then submit my answer so that my browser opens a new page with the elements i chose. I was able to select the argument but when I press the button "Search", it doesnt take into account my selections. Here are the html of the listbox :

```
<select size="10" name="lbSources" id="lbSources" class="form" onkeypress="return OnKeyPressEnterSubmit('btnSearch', event);" style="width:250px;">
    <option value="UK_P">01 net</option>
    <option value="UKA_P">01 net - Hors-série</option>
    <option value="QAA_P">2 Rives, Les (Sorel-Tracy, QC)</option>
    <option value="WV_P">24 Heures (Suisse)</option>
    <option value="FJ_P">Abitibi Express Rouyn-Noranda/Abitibi-Ouest</option>
   (...)
```

and the html of the search button :

```
 <input type="image" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" src="/images/interface/buttons/SearchFR_on.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))">
```

And here is how my Python code looks like:

```
selectBox = browser.find_element_by_name("lbSources")
selectBox.send_keys("UK_P")
browser.find_element_by_name("btnSearch").click()
```

So it first selects a box but then... Nothing..

Comment: what is the actual problem, the select option is working but, search click is not working?

Comment: That ' s it but it worked with comments !

Answer (score 0):

Use Select class to click from dropdown:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('lbSources'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('UK_P')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct xpath to select the list option and then trigger `onkeypress` event on the list box.

```
item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lbSources']/option[@value='UK_P']")
# click on the list item
item.click()
# now trigger onKeyPress event
list_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lbSources']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('onkeypress', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",list_box)
```